# Different materials on same object in different view layers/render layers

Tags: materials, render-layers

Is there a way to apply different materials to the same object in different view layers/render layers?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93043/linking-the-mesh-and-location-of-objects-with-different-materials-in-different-s/