# How to organize different animations when you didn't finish your scene yet?

Tags: animation, objects, workflow, scene

I want to have different scenes to create different movements of my objects. When I create or change an object, I want it to be created or changed in all these scenes. Only the animations shall not be linked.

Is there a way to link all objects without their animations between scenes?

Comment: are you talking about the Blender "scenes" within the same file, or are you talking about creating a brand new Blender file.

Comment: @moonboots I don't want to create different files because I would have to update everything I change in every file. I'd like to have different scenes in which everything but the allocation of the actions is updated :)

Comment: the File > Link function precisely allows you to make all the animations you want with an object, but its mesh is only editable in the original file, so if you change the original mesh it will be replicated on all its linked instances

Comment: On the opposite, if you create a new Scene in a file, all the instances of the same object will have the same animation. So I may miss something but I don't think you can do that with Scenes. What you could do, though, is make a Linked Copy Scene, then make Linked Duplications of your object (alt D instead of shift D): the instances are independent, but if you change the mesh of one instance it will change the mesh of all the others.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93043/linking-the-mesh-and-location-of-objects-with-different-materials-in-different-s/93055#93055

Answer (score 1):

So I may be wrong but here is what I think you should do from what I understand:

As you don't want to use the *File > Link* function and as you absolutely want to use *Scenes*, I think the best way to do it is to create a *New Scene > Linked Copy* mode, so that the objects stay linked from a scene to another, then you need to make linked duplications of your object (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), so that if you make any edit on one instance of this object, it will be replicated on all the other instances on all linked copy scene.

Why linked duplications? Because if you simply reuse the same object from a scene to another you won't be able to change the animation of one instance without changing the animation of all the other instances.

Comment: Thank you a lot! That works very well for armature actions and would be what I look for! But it doesn't seem to work for shape key actions with the exaclty same process. Very strange. They get updated in their linked duplications.

Am I doing anything wrong? Do shape key actions work completely different?

Comment: yes you're right, it looks like the limitation of this method  :/  I didn't know shapekeys were replicated on the linked duplications by the way

Comment: Do you know a way to summerize actions?
It would be helpful to activate a group of actions on different objects by one klick :)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, could you give an example? You can copy an action (Animation Data) of an object with ctrl L but I'm not sure that's you want

Comment: I mean: I klick an "action folder" or something and every object in the scene gets the right action that belongs to each other.
Very specific - I know :D

Comment: on the NLA, you can select a group of strips and duplicate it, maybe it's the closest thing to what you need?

Comment: You're right! I could just order my actions and objects on the NLA in the timeline!
Thank you so much! That's better than the scene idea.