# Link camera animation between scenes

Tags: camera, workflow, linked-data

I have two scenes that are composited together.

Scene A has a camera with animation.

I need the camera in scene B to have the same animation but different camera settings.

I know this should be simple enough to setup but I can't get it working today.

Comment: I think the solution presented here will work the same https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93043

Comment: I cannot just parent it to an empty as there is also animation of the focal length that needs to be linked between the cameras.
Basically I want to link everything except the DOF settings

Comment: I think I did it by using `Ctrl` + `L` > *Animation Data*