# Within same blender file, how to link objects to new scene and override position (blender 3.5)?

Tags: linked-data, scene, library-overrides

I'm feeling like the main workflow for linking and library overrides is when the object of interest is saved in a separate blender file. My question is whether we can perform linking and library overrides in the same file?

I've tried creating two scenes (source,dest), and then making a cube in source. I then press Ctrl-L to pull up the link options and select `link objects to scene` and then say `dest`.

[image]

This all goes ok, but then any time I try to move the cube when I'm in the destination scene it also moves the cube in the source scene. That's somewhat expected since I haven't overriden anything or made the destination cube local.

My problem here is that when I go to override the cube in either scene I only see greyed out options.
[image]

What's strange is in the outliner I can actually right click and get the non greyed out library overrides option, but it doesn't appear to do anything: moving the cube in either scene causes same motion in the other.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*My question is whether we can perform linking and library overrides in the same file?*" As far as I know you can. Either use [collection instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/are-groups-or-sketchup-like-components-feasible-in-blender), or see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93043/linking-the-mesh-and-location-of-objects-with-different-materials-in-different-s

Comment: Thanks, looking at those next/